# how the enum type is used to allocate registers

Tags: c

I can't understand the purpose of the code below. When I read the sdk of octeon, how is the enum type used to allocate registers? And how can I use cvmx_fau_reg_64_t?

```
/*************************  FAU allocation ********************************/
/* The fetch and add registers are allocated here.  They are arranged
    in order of descending size so that all alignment constraints are
    automatically met.
    The enums are linked so that the following enum continues allocating
    where the previous one left off, so the numbering within each
    enum always starts with zero.  The macros take care of the address
    increment size, so the values entered always increase by 1.
    FAU registers are accessed with byte addresses. */

#define CVMX_FAU_REG_64_ADDR(x) ((x <<3) + CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START)
typedef enum
{
    CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START          = 0, 
    CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END            = CVMX_FAU_REG_64_ADDR(0),
} cvmx_fau_reg_64_t;

#define CVMX_FAU_REG_32_ADDR(x) ((x <<2) + CVMX_FAU_REG_32_START)
typedef enum
{
    CVMX_FAU_REG_32_START          = CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END,
    CVMX_FAU_REG_32_END            = CVMX_FAU_REG_32_ADDR(0),
} cvmx_fau_reg_32_t;

#define CVMX_FAU_REG_16_ADDR(x) ((x <<1) + CVMX_FAU_REG_16_START)
typedef enum
{
    CVMX_FAU_REG_16_START          = CVMX_FAU_REG_32_END,
    CVMX_FAU_REG_16_END            = CVMX_FAU_REG_16_ADDR(0),
} cvmx_fau_reg_16_t;

#define CVMX_FAU_REG_8_ADDR(x) ((x) + CVMX_FAU_REG_8_START)
typedef enum {
    CVMX_FAU_REG_8_START           = CVMX_FAU_REG_16_END,
    CVMX_FAU_REG_8_END             = CVMX_FAU_REG_8_ADDR(0),
} cvmx_fau_reg_8_t;

/* The name CVMX_FAU_REG_AVAIL_BASE is provided to indicate the first available
   FAU address that is not allocated in cvmx-config.h. This is 64 bit aligned. */
#define CVMX_FAU_REG_AVAIL_BASE ((CVMX_FAU_REG_8_END + 0x7) & (~0x7ULL))
#define CVMX_FAU_REG_END (2048)
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, enum type is similar to signed integer data type. This is how you should use the `cvmx_fau_reg_64_t`:

```
cvmx_fau_reg_64_t myRegister;

myRegister=CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START;

//Do something with the *myRegister* variable

myRegister=CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cavium OCTEON FAU registers are actually supported by a range of special memory that is enforced to be Atomic, via tag operations and acessed via IOBDMA.

So you only get to specify the Register number and Size.  You SHOULD be using cvmx-fau APIs  like  cvmx_fau_fetch_and_add64(fau_reg_64_t reg, value), or similar for  Add, Increment.   OCTEON architecture will guarantee that all Read/Writes are **Atomic** using Tag operations and IOBDMA bus.

Your code should just choose and refer to the particular FAU index, and decide to use them for 64/32/16/8 bit values/ counters. The rest is all via the SDK provided FAU functions **only**.

The cvmx-config can define an initial few for you, and then you can add more if needed in your code. These will go after FAU_AVAIL_BASE.

At no point should you be directly defining/manipulating/de-refrencing those memory locations.  These are **not like** normal 64 / 32 bit variables or pointers.

Paxym